# Avoid client-side sorting of rows in JQGrid with Multi Grouping 

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins, jqgrid

I've noticed that multi grouping in JQGrid elicits rows sorting to be rearranged inline once the list of values is retrieved through ajax getJSon(). 
Sometimes the reordering splits groups of the same elements in more than one group, as it should be.

I guess the solution is to avoid client side re-sorting of JQGrid rows, with the aim to definitively **reuse the same order given inside the JSON without changes** --- as returned by the server.

I'm using the following configuration :

```
jq("#myGrid").jqGrid({
  datatype: 'local',
  data: myvar.detail,  // a well formatted json locally stored
  colNames: [ ....],
  colModel: [
    {name:'nome_attr',index:'nome_attr', sorttype: function () {return 1;}, editable:true, editrules:{required:true}, editoptions:{size:27}, align:'center'},
    {name:'desc_attr', index:'desc_attr', sorttype: function () {return 1;}, editable:true, editrules:{required:false}, edittype: "textarea",editoptions:{rows:5, cols:25}, hidden:true},
    {name:'valore',index:'valore', sorttype: function () {return 1;},editable:true, editrules:{required:false}, editoptions:{size:30}, width:120},
     ....
          ],
   loadonce: false,     // to dis-able sorting on client side
   sortable: false,     
   grouping:true,
   groupingView : {
         groupField : ['nome_attr', 'valore'],
         groupColumnShow: [false,false],
         groupText : ['{0}'],
         groupCollapse: true,
         groupDataSorted: false, 
         groupSorted: false, 
         groupOrder: false
        }
  });
```

Notice (1) I'm already using the workaround to disable the sort type

```
 sorttype: function () {return 1;}
```

as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10977583/jqgrid-grouping-deactivating-client-side-sorting-on-page-navigation), and that in `"#myGrid"` is a sub-grid, where the `datatype:  local`, means the rows have been previously retrieved in the container grid.

Does anybody knows which is the configuration of the `colModel` attribute and the `groupingView` parameters to be set in order to avoid in-line re-sorting in case of Multi Grouping ?

thanks in advance,

Michele

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One workaround to fix the automatic sort is to allow the client to work in order to re-produce the same list of values (recreating the same order).

First, prepare a JScript function forcing the right order value for each grouped column:

```
   /** 
    * Sort type in subgrid's gropued rows
    */
   function sortGroup(cellValus, rowData, ty) {     
       if(ty==='attribute_1')
        return rowData.attr1_order;
       else if(ty==='attribute_2')
        return rowData.attr2_order;
    }
```

Second, inject the desired order values in the `colModel`.

Third, trigger the previous function inside the `sorttype` in each grouped column, using the column type to know which group the order belongs:

```
  colModel: [
     {name:'nome_attr',index:'nome_attr', sorttype: function (cellValus, rowData) {return sortGroup(cellValus, rowData, 'attribute_1')}, editable:true, editrules:{required:true}, editoptions:{size:27}, align:'center'},
     {name:'desc_attr', index:'desc_attr', editable:true, editrules:{required:false}, edittype: "textarea",editoptions:{rows:5, cols:25}, hidden:true},
     {name:'valore',index:'valore', sorttype: function (cellValus, rowData) {return sortGroup(cellValus, rowData, 'attribute_2')},editable:true, editrules:{required:false}, editoptions:{size:30}, width:120},
      .....
     {name:'attr1_order',index:'attr1_order', editable:false, hidden:true},
     {name:'attr2_order',index:'attr2_order', editable:false, hidden:true}
     ]
```